# Likelihood ratio test disagrees with cross-validation results

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, likelihood-ratio

I have computed two logistic models of the same data (for different formulas) in R, and compared them using likelihood ratio test:

```
g1 <- glm(Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V3, data, family=binomial)
g2 <- glm(Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V4, data, family=binomial)
lrtest(g1, g2)
```

With results:

```
  #Df  LogLik Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1  14 -49.458                        
2  14 -50.357  0 1.798  < 2.2e-16 ***
```

So, if I interpret the test correctly, the likelihood ratio test says the second model is worse than the first.

Then I made a cross-validation run on these models:

```
trControl <- trainControl('repeatedcv', number=10, repeats=50)
c1 <- train(
    Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V3, data, method='glm',
    family=binomial, trControl=trControl)
c2 <- train(
    Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V4, data, method='glm',
    family=binomial, trControl=trControl)
```

With results:

```
# first model
  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.818     0.571  0.098        0.232   

# second model
  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.826     0.585  0.091        0.217
```

So, if anything, the second model looks slightly (probably not enough to be significant) better than the first.

As far as I understand, given that the likelihood ratios are computed on the training data, they don't reflect the out-of-sample performance, whereas cross-validation results are by design better estimates. Looks like a typical case of overfitting.

Is my understanding correct? If so, why even bother with likelihood ratio tests? How should I compare these models correctly?

EDIT:

As suggested by comments, Vuong test:

```
> vuong(g1, g2)

Vuong test for non-nested models

Model 1 log-likelihood: -49
Model 2 log-likelihood: -50
Observations: 158
Test statistic: 0.3

Neither model is significantly preferred (p = 0.76)
```

This result seem to agree with the outcome of the cross-validation procedure. Though, I'm still wondering if this the proper way by theory.

Comment: whats your sample size?

Comment: Your two models are not nested -- so (i) what specific test are you actually running there? It's not quite clear to me you're doing something that makes sense.  (ii) what package is this `lrtest` a function from? [The difference in AIC of your two models would seem to be fairly modest; there's not much between these two models]

Comment: @Glen_b probably the `lmtest` package. But indeed I think the _answer_ here is that LR tests are invalid for non nested models. You would need maybe Vuong's closeness test, except that it won't be as easy as calling a function in a popular R package: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuong%27s_closeness_test

Comment: @ssdecontrol Vuong's test can be found in some packages (arguably not popular, perhaps).

Comment: @Glen_b you're right, I just found it in `games` and `pscl`

Comment: @robin.datadrivers: 158 cases. @Glen_b: I confirm, `lmtest` package. @ssdecontrol: I was never formally trained in statistics, so I often miss some basic information like that the LR test is not valid for non-nested models—thank you for pointing this out. I ran the Vuong test from the `games` package, results edited into the question.

Comment: One more question: what is your goal of comparison?  Do you want a p-value?  Or is it good enough to know the cross-validation results?

Comment: @BenBolker: My goal is to check whether I should measure V3 or V4 in order to predict the outcome in a potential experiment procedure. In this specific experiment, measuring both is possible, but costly/time-consuming, and so far the common practice was to measure V3. V4 happens to be a newly discovered alternative and I wanted to check how its performance compares to V3 — with a bit of a hunch it's basically equally good.

Answer (score 3):

The cross-validation measures you seem to be computing are discontinuous improper accuracy scores.  They are designed not to agree with proper scoring methods such as likelihood-based measures and the Brier score.  Improper scores are optimized by selecting the wrong model with the wrong features and giving them the wrong weights.  This will be covered in the upcoming 2nd edition of *Regression Modeling Strategies* and is in my course handouts which you can get to from http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms.  There are some good papers on proper scoring rules but start with looking up Brier score and generalized $R^2$.

Comment: This seems potentially useful but is also very terse ... pointer to a reference?  Is this covered in *Regresion Modeling Strategies*? (I don't think so, but I don't have my copy handy ...)